# Universal set as a collection of objects

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers

The universal set $U$ can be defined as $U = \{x : x=x\}$, which is equivalent to $\forall x[x \in U \leftrightarrow x = x]$. Since $x=x$ is a tautology, then we infer $\forall x \in U$. This definition tells us that every free variable in the scope of the universal quantifier is an element of $U$. Since $x \in U$ means $\{x\} \subseteq U$, then $\forall x \in U$ could be rewritten as $\forall x[\{x\} \subseteq U ]$ or $\forall X[X \subseteq U]$. Therefore, every set $X$ is a subset of the universal set $U$.

However, I've seen in some proofs and commentaries cases which define the universal set as a finite collection of objects, for example $U = \{ x_0, x_1\}$. This formula is equivalent to $\forall x[x \in U \leftrightarrow x \in \{x_0, x_1\}]$ and to $\forall x[x \in U \leftrightarrow x = x_0 \lor x=x_1\}]$. Compatibilization problems with the classical definition $\forall x [x \in U \leftrightarrow x=x]$ arise when we substitute $x$ by a free variable that is not $x_0$ and $x_1$. For example, $x_2 \in U \leftrightarrow x_2=x_0 \lor x_2=x_1$ returns $x_2 \notin U$, while $x_2 \in U \leftrightarrow x_2=x_2$ is equivalent to $x_2 \in U$. Thus, we have an apparent contradiction between the standard definition of universal set and its definition as a finite collection of objects.

I was inclined to think that my mistake would lie on the impossibility of universally instantiating the formula $\forall x[x \in U \leftrightarrow x = x_0 \lor x=x_1\}]$ with a variable $x_2$ that is not in the universal set $\{ x_0, x_1\}$. To formalize such notion, we would have to explicit that the domain of this formula itself is "limited" to the defined universal set, thus considering it equivalent to $\forall x \in U[x \in U \leftrightarrow x = x_0 \lor x=x_1\}]$. Therefore, we would have by universal instantiation $x_2 \in U \rightarrow [x_2 \in U \leftrightarrow x_2=x_0 \lor x_2=x_1]$, which is a tautology, since $x_2 \notin U$. But then again, from the formula $\forall x[x \in U \leftrightarrow x=x]$, we would conclude $x_2 \in U$, so the contradiction remains.

Is the universal set not definable as a collection of finite objects?

Comment: In first-order logic, the "universal set" defined by the predicate $x=x$ is relative to the domain of the interpretation: if the domain is finite, then the universal set will be finite. If the domain is infinite, also the universal set will be.

Comment: If we have $D = \{ a, b \}$, we may add to the language two individual constant $c_1$ and $c_2$ denoting the two objects and thus we may say that $\forall x [x \in \{ x \mid (x=x) \} \leftrightarrow (x=c_1 \lor x=c_2)]$

Comment: But the "universal set" is a object in the interpretation: the domain $D$, and we instantiate an universal formula $\forall x Px$ with a *term*, i.e. either a variable or a constant (or a complex term), and terms are syntactical objects, i.e. "names".

Comment: The language $\mathcal L$ has an unlimited number of individual variables : $x_i$ but we may interpret it also with interpretations having finite domains. There is no contradiction form the fact that the number of variables may be infinite (but every formula is a finite expression: thus, only a finite number of variables may occur in them)

Comment: If you work in set theory, like e.g. Zermelo-Frenkel, the concept of [Universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set) leads to paradoxes.

Comment: Mr Allegranza, thank you for the reply. I still have some questions: Let's work exclusively in first-order logic. a. Given the domain $D$ and the universal set $U$, such that $\forall x \in D [x=x \leftrightarrow x \in U]$,  can $D=U$? b. If $D$ is not equal to $U$, then can $D$ not be a subset of $U$?

Comment: I mean in question b, can $U$ be a subset of $D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

Consider formulas in the first-order language of *arithmetic*, with $0,+,\times, \le$.

The "natural" domain of interpretation is the set $\mathbb N = \{ 0,1,2,\ldots \}$ of *natural* numbers.

We can prove e.g. that $\forall x (x \le 1 \to P(x)) \leftrightarrow (P(0) \land P(1))$, but we cannot prove that $\forall x (x \ge 0 \to P(x)) \leftrightarrow (P(0) \land P(1) \land \ldots)$ because the infinite-long conjunction to the right is not a syntactically correct formula: in FOL, formulas are expression of *finite* length.

We can prove instead:  $\forall x (x \ge 0 \to P(x)) \rightarrow P(n)$, for every $n$.

But you can consider so-called [Infinitary Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/), i.e. logic based on

> "languages which can be obtained in a straightforward manner from first-order languages by allowing conjunctions, disjunctions and, possibly, quantifier sequences, to be of infinite length."

---

Regarding the "universal set" $U$, we can mimic it in predicate logic with an universal predicate $U(x) \leftrightarrow (x=x)$, in which case the formula $∀x[x=x ↔ U(x)]$ becomes a tautology.

Comment: If we define the universal set, for example, as $\forall [x \in \{x_0, x_1\} \leftrightarrow x=x]$, then, if we instantiate the definition with a variable that is not $x_0$ and $x_1$, we end up with a contradiction. Is it correct to say that the definition of the universal set as a finite collection of objects limits the universe of its own definition, since $\forall [x \in \{x_0, x_1\} \leftrightarrow x=x]$ is equivalent to $\forall [x=x \rightarrow [x \in \{x_0, x_1\} \leftrightarrow x=x]]$ and to $\forall [(x \in \{x_0, x_1\}) \rightarrow [x \in \{x_0, x_1\} \leftrightarrow x=x]]$?

Comment: My point is, I can't see a way to make the definitions $\forall x[x \in U \leftrightarrow x=x]$ and $\forall x [x \in U \leftrightarrow x=x_0 \lor x=x_1]$ compatible with each other.

Comment: @TylerD007 - they are not. The first one holds in **every** model, while the second one only in models with at most two elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, Mr Allegranza.